# FontWeight does not stay the same in published project

Tags: wpf, publishing, text-styling

I have a WPF application. My project has compiled and I published the project without any error.

In debug mode I set text's `FontWeight` to bold, but when I published my project, each text's `FontWeight` is not set to bold. How can I solve this problem?
Example Code:

```
<Label FontWeight="Bold">Test</Label>
```

Comment: Are you using a standard system font or did you change it to something custom?

Comment: Yes I'm using `Verdana` or `Arial Black`.

Comment: Hmm ... those usually come [pre-installed with windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_typefaces_included_with_Microsoft_Windows) so that's not the problem.

Comment: "In debug mode I set text's FontWeight to bold"? How do you set thw FontWeight property in "debug mode"...?